# How to connect two Magento2 instance by API?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I want to create one one product from backend then it should be automatically created into second M2

Answer (score 3):

**STEP1:** In order to access the REST API of Magento 2 we need authentication, to get authentication you need to get admin token using admin username and password using below code.

```
<?php
    //Get Admin token from admin user
    $apiURL="http://baseurl/rest/en/V1/integration/admin/token";
    $data = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "admin@123");
    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init($apiURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json","Content-Length: ".strlen($data_string)));
    $token = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $token = json_decode($token);
    curl_close ($ch);
```

Here use your URL instead of `"http://baseurl/rest/en/V1/integration/admin/token"`
"en" is your store view code. And replace username and password with yours.

**STEP2:** Use your admin token to access catalog product repository, before this creates a product array in the form of

```
$productPost = array(
  "product" => array(
  "id"=> 50,
  "sku"=> "string",
  "name"=> "string",
  "attribute_set_id"=> 4,
  "price"=> 4,
  "status"=> 100,
  "visibility"=> 4,
  "type_id"=> "simple",
  "weight"=> 0,
  "extension_attributes"=> array(
    "website_ids"=> [1],
    "stock_item"=> array(
      "item_id"=> 47,
      "product_id"=> 50,
      "stock_id"=> 1,
      "qty"=> 100,
      "is_in_stock"=> true,
      "is_qty_decimal"=> true,
      "use_config_min_qty"=> true,
      "min_qty"=> 0,
      "use_config_min_sale_qty"=> 0,
      "min_sale_qty"=> 0,
      "use_config_max_sale_qty"=> true,
      "max_sale_qty"=> 0,
      "use_config_backorders"=> true,
      "backorders"=> 0,
      "use_config_notify_stock_qty"=> true,
      "notify_stock_qty"=> 0,
      "use_config_qty_increments"=> true,
      "qty_increments"=> 0,
      "use_config_enable_qty_inc"=> true,
      "enable_qty_increments"=> true,
      "use_config_manage_stock"=> true,
      "manage_stock"=> true,
      "low_stock_date"=> "string",
      "is_decimal_divided"=> true,
      "stock_status_changed_auto"=> 0,
      "extension_attributes"=> array()
    ),
  ),
  "options"=> [],
  "media_gallery_entries"=> [],
  "tier_prices"=> [],
  "custom_attributes"=> []
)
);
```

This is demo array, you can get whole array in this url `"https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger"` in `catalogProductRepositoryV1 -> post /V1/products -> Model Schema`

**STEP3:** Now use token and product array in catalogProductRepositoryV1 API to create a product

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://baseUrl/rest/en/V1/products');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($productPost));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$token;
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
print_r($result);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Try this code and let me know if you have any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 approaches to achieve this.

**1. Event/Observer way**: Get the product data using catalog_product_save_after event and send it to second Magento instance.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
    <observer name="test_name" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
</event>
</config>
```

Productsaveafter.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $_product = $observer->getProduct(); // Get product data
        /* Write REST API code here to send data to your send Magento instance */
    }
}
```

You can see REST API examples [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/configurable-product/config-product-intro.html) using which you can prepare product object and send data to your send Magento instance.

**2. Plugin way**: You can use `afterSave` plugin on `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository` and send data to your second Magento instance. I believe you already know how to use [plugins](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html).

***Note:*** Here are a few tutorials which will help you getting started with REST API in Magento 2:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/index.html 
https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-api/ 
https://magehit.com/blog/how-to-use-rest-api-in-magento-2/

To connect to your second Magento instance:

- Create a admin user in second Magento instance and assign the catalog access. Let's say you have created account with username admin and password admin123.
- Let's assume your second Magento's base url is m2.com
- You need to create access token for your second Magento's instance. You can create using using postman.
- In postnam send a POST request `m2.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token` using below configurations

Headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Body:

```
{
"username": "admin",
"password": "admin123"
}
```

- From your post request you will get a token something like `qgfu59ns024dkzfxhh6ado2hpqmnduocs2`, which you will use to create product data in M2.
- Next you send a POST request to your m2 instance at url `m2.com/rest/V1/products` with following configuration which will create a product in M2.

Headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer qgfu59ns024dkzfxhh6ado2hpqmnduocs2
```

Body:

```
{
  "product": {
    "sku": "190",
    "name": "test product",
    "price": 100.00,
    "status": 1,
    "type_id": "simple",
    "attribute_set_id":4,
    "weight": 1
  }
}
```

After above steps product should be created in your Magento 2 instance.

Now what you need to do is you need to prepare above url and product data in your observer code and send data to your Magento instance following the same    code as above.

Comment: I know how to use plugins but I don't know how to use Rest Api  and how to connect with another magento instance

Comment: I have added some rest api tutorial links in the answer. You need to created token of your second Magento instance using which you can connect to your second Magento instance and create product using rest api of your second Magento's instance.